# Projection Valued Measure Form of the Spectral Theorem (Unbounded)

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Can anyone provide a reference to a nice proof of the projection valued measure form of the spectral theorem for unbounded operators? Many textbooks simply omit the proof.

Comment: Try Rudin Functional analysis chapter 13.

Answer (score 0):

One reference for the construction of the spectral measure of a finite family of strongly commuting, unbounded, normal operators is the book 'Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space' by Schmüdgen.

*Schmüdgen, Konrad*, Unbounded self-adjoint operators on Hilbert space, Graduate Texts in Mathematics 265. Dordrecht: Springer (ISBN 978-94-007-4752-4/hbk; 978-94-007-4753-1/ebook). xx, 432 p. (2012). [ZBL1257.47001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1257.47001).